# Use of importing scss in react component

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am trying to understand a project and there I found an interesting way of applying styles to the component.  I would like to know what are the advantages that one can get by using this type of styling.

```
**productRow.scss**

    #price{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

productRow.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {price} from '../styles/productRow.scss';//Here extracted price from the styles file

const ProductRow = ({data}) =>{
    return(
        <div>
        <p >{data.name}-<span id={price}>{data.price}</span></p>
        </div>
);};

ProductRow.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object,
    ToggleDetails: PropTypes.bool
};

export default ProductRow;
```

Comment: This question is opinion based and not a good format for StackOverflow. But this style of importing with CSS modules is currently the best way to deal with CSS.

Comment: I didn't get about "not a good format for stack overflow". Does my way of framing the question is incorrect?